# IO for julia reading fortran files

Tags: fortran, complex-numbers, julia

Noob question:

I have the output of a complex matrix done in Fortran, the contents looks like this:

(-0.594209719263636,1.463867815703586E-006)
(-0.783378034185788,-0.182301028756558) (-0.794024313844809,0.128219337674814)
(0.592814294881930,4.069892201461069E-002)

I want to read and use this data in a julia program.

1. No, I don't want to change the writting format, I would like to learn how to strip off
   the "trash" characters like '(', or ','. This may be useful for arbitrary Input files.

2.I have tried with the following code:

```
file = open(pathtofilename, "r")
data_str = readall(ifile)
data_numbers_str = split(data_str)
data_numbers = split(data_numbers_str, ['('])
```

However, the manual is not quite self-explanatory [http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.2/stdlib/base/?highlight=split].

Comment: Perhaps it might be simpler to write real and imaginary parts of the matrix separately and combine them in Julia?

Comment: For sure, but I want to know how to manipulate arbitrary text sequences of IOfiles in Julia and this seems a good start, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I'd do

```
data = "(-0.594209719263636,1.463867815703586E-006) (-0.783378034185788,-0.182301028756558) (-0.794024313844809,0.128219337674814) (0.592814294881930,4.069892201461069E-002)"

function pair_to_complex(pair)
    nums = float(split(pair[2:end-1], ","))
    return Complex(nums...)
end
numbers = map(pair_to_complex, split(data, " "))
```

To explain

- The `pair[2:end-1]` removes the parenthesis
- I then split that on the `,` to get an array with two numbers, still as strings
- I convert them to Float64 with `float()`, obtaining an array of floats
- I make a new complex number. The `...` splats the array out so it provides the two arguments to `Complex` - I could have done `Complex(nums[1],nums[2])`
- I then apply this logic using `map` to every term in the data.

Comment: do you know how to print the numbers array with all the digits? I'm getting uglies ...fx numbers:
`print(a)
Complex{Float32}[-0.59420973f0 + 1.4638678f-6im,-0.783378f0 - 0.18230103f0im,-0.7940243f0 + 0.12821934f0im,0.59281427f0 + 0.040698923f0im]`

Comment: It looks like you have Float32s, instead of Float64s - how'd that happen?

Comment: It is because I did a little different than your code above. I am defining `matrix_array = zeros(Complex64, dim*dim)`. Strangely it gives: `typeof(matrix_array) Array{Complex{Float32},1}`

Comment: Complex64 is a pair of Float32. You want Complex128, or better yet, something like Complex{eltype(nums)}.

Comment: Yep, in fact another way to do it is just generate a Float64 array and then apply complex(array). Anyway, I think this is not said in the manual. Perhaps should be.